# Access to separate pixel of JPEG image in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, jpeg

In my android project I need to get access for each separate pixel of JPEG image. Image created by built-in photo application. I try to convert JPEG into `Bitmap` class instance, but `OutOfMemoryException` was thrown. After searching info about this problem I have found the following solution: resize image! But quality of image is important in my project, and i can't resize it. Is there any way to get each-pixel access?

Comment: See my answer to [this question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728374/opening-jpegs-on-android-i-get-an-outofmemoryexception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your image is too big and the quality is important i suppose the best way is to use or create your own class to cut the image in zone (eg : 50*50 px) , there is several jpeg info class in the internet to help you understand how work jpeg files.

Have you tried BufferedImage ? (it's not in the sdk but maybe usable)

Answer (score 0):

The nature of jpeg makes it very hard to get the value of a single pixel. The main reason is that the data is not byte aligned, another is that everything is encoded in blocks that can be of sizes 8x16, 16x8 and 8x8. Also, you need to handle subsampling of chroma values.

If the image contains restart markers, maybe you can skip into the image so you don't have to decode the whole image before getting the pixel value.

Comment: This makes no sense. A jpg may be encoded with blocks but decoding a jpg can be done such that all the pixels fill an array. After all, your screen is nothing more than array of pixels.

Comment: The OP wanted to know if there were a way to resize a jpeg without first decoding it. To do that you need to access arbitrary pixels in the jpeg. This is hard to do because of the reasons specified. I'm sorry it doesn't make sense to you.