# Opening jpegs on Android - I get an OutOfMemoryException

Tags: android, image, bitmap, jpeg

In my application I need to process images taken by Android's built-in applications. They're saved into JPEG format, and I need to get access to each pixel. I tried to create a `Bitmap` instance from the jpeg image, but very often I get an `OutOfMemoryException`. I can't resize or crop image. Does a solution exist?

Comment: Can you explain the use case, what do you need to do with the images? Maybe there are alternative ways of doing it.

Comment: I need to execute various Digital Image Processing algorithms, such as Binarization, convert to grey-scale, different filters etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [BitmapRegionDecoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html). It is available since API level 10.  You can decode parts of an image file and process each chunk.

Answer (score 1):

BitmapFactory will often throw OutOfMemoryExceptions and I'm afraid that I've never really discovered any workarounds.  It seems to be doing its own memory management, and sometimes it really isn't capable of parsing an image.  In a couple of applications I've worked on that had to deal with images heavily, I just had to catch the exception and then leave blank spots in the UI when I couldn't get an image parsed.  Sometimes, if you try again later, those images will parse, presumably when the internal memory state of BitmapFactory is working better.

When I was working on a J2ME application, I tried to find a pure Java open source JPEG parser so I could use it on phones that didn't have built-in JPEG support.  Turns out that such a thing is difficult to find, and the closest I could find was buried in the depths of the Eclipse source.  I was able to take that source, de-Eclipsify it and try it out.  It did have the virtue of reading in things line by line (although I'm not sure how it would have done with progressive scan JPEGs), but it was ridiculously slow on our J2ME devices (particularly since they were mostly the lower end ones) so we didn't end up using it for anything.